# looking for a simple database extension with image support for typo3

Tags: typo3

I'm making a typo3 site and need to have a database which consists two tables: manufacturer and category. a manufacturer can have multiple categories and, besides company name and link, has a few images which are displayed in a gallery.

In the frontend, there are two differnet pages which list the categories. A click on a category leads to a page where the manufacturers of this category are listed. The categories and manufacturers need to editable in the backend.

I have thought about creating classical typo3 content elements, but this has the disadvantage that there is no database structure in the backend and therefore it would be required to create two of the same content elements for different pages.

Clearly, having a database is the better method. My knowledge of typo3 is not the best and my question is: what would be the best approach to implement such a database? Is there an extension for such cases or do i need to create an extension using extbase? And, in the latter case, how difficult would it be to create an editor for the backend in which the content can be entered into the database and the images can be uploaded.

I did hours of research but wasn't able to figure out what the best approach would be. I'm not looking for some ready-made solutions (except for the case that there is one for this specific problem) but for some hints which point me into the right direction. I have no problem with learning how to create an extension; i just would like to know if it's worth the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[Extension Builder](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder)** to create new extension with all elements you need: additional tables, fields, FE plugins, custom CE's, even BE modules just with *click'-click'* solution.

It just matter of several minutes to build models properly... in such case it generates valid TCA, so you've got backend ready to use out-of-the-box. For FE you'll need to put some additional effort.

Summarizing, yes it's worth the time.

And sorry... I must mention: [**TYPO3** (*not typo3*) is written with uppercase, always](http://typo3.org/about/the-brand/style-guide/the-typo3-spelling/)